# How to add scrolling text widget in Kivy?

Tags: android, python-2.7, scroll, scrollview, kivy

I am new in Kivy. I would like to create an app that takes user text input, then display it. But when the user input is very long, I want the display area to be scrollable.

I have done some tutorials and can do both things separately, but I have troubles putting them altogether.

Here is the code to allow scrollable text:

```
__version__ = '1.0.1'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import warnings
import string
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrolllabelLabel>:
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 50
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
''')

class ScrolllabelLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('srgsdrgsdfh dsfg dvgf vgsdfv srfvsdfsdrfv sevrv sdrfv serv serv serv servsrd vsv srvsdrfvvv' * 10)

runTouchApp(ScrolllabelLabel())
```

And here is the code to display what you type:

```
__version__ = '1.0.1'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import warnings
import string
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_x=None, width="600dp")

        self.lbl0 = Label(text='Tap and type a word/phrase below') # create a label instance
        grid.add_widget(self.lbl0) # physically add the label onto the layout

        self.txt1 = TextInput(text='', multiline=False) # create a text input instance
        grid.add_widget(self.txt1) # physically add the text input onto the layout

        self.lbl1 = Label(text='Display') # create a label instance
        grid.add_widget(self.lbl1) # physically add the label onto the layout

        btn1 = Button(text='Press') # create a button instance
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.mirror) # binding the button with the function below
        grid.add_widget(btn1) 

        return grid

    def mirror(self, userInput):
        self.lbl1.text = self.txt1.text

SomeApp().run()
```

But I can't combine them:

```
__version__ = '1.0.1'

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import warnings
import string
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrolllabelLabel>:
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 50
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
''')

class ScrolllabelLabel(ScrollView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.txt0 = StringProperty()

class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_x=None, width="600dp")

        self.lbl0 = Label(text='Tap and type a word/phrase below') # create a label instance
        grid.add_widget(self.lbl0) # physically add the label onto the layout

        self.txt1 = TextInput(text='', multiline=False) # create a text input instance
        grid.add_widget(self.txt1) # physically add the text input onto the layout

        btn1 = Button(text='Press') # create a button instance
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.displayFunc) # binding the button with the function below
        grid.add_widget(btn1) 

        # Add scrolling text
        """self.lbl1 = Label(text='Display') # create a label instance
        grid.add_widget(self.lbl1) # physically add the label onto the layout"""
        scrollWidget = ScrolllabelLabel(text=self.lbl1.text)
        grid.add_widget(scrollWidget)

        return grid

    def displayFunc(self, userInput):
        self.lbl1.text = self.txt1

SomeApp().run()
```

I got this error:

```
 AttributeError: 'SomeApp' object has no attribute 'lbl1'
```

Comment: `self.lbl1.text = self.txt1` edit to scrollwidget, that's your attribute error and use self.txt1._text_, because you want text property, not the widget itself.

Comment: How do I perform your suggestion of "self.lbl1.text = self.txt1 edit to scrollwidget"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you did is `multiline=False` therefore the app will behave that way and doesn't matter how big you make `TextInput`, it'll still be one line. Use `multiline=True` for your default TextInput and it'll wrap input properly.

Then I see you already have a body for scrollable label, so just use the default one, use that default class and feed the `text` variable of `ScrolllabelLabel` in your first file with your output.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
import warnings
import string
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<ScrolllabelLabel>:
    Label:
        text: root.text
        font_size: 50
        text_size: self.width, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.texture_size[1]
''')

class ScrolllabelLabel(ScrollView):
    text = StringProperty('')
class SomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        grid = GridLayout(cols=1, size_hint_x=None, width="600dp")

        self.lbl0 = Label(text='Tap and type a word/phrase below') # create a label instance
        grid.add_widget(self.lbl0) # physically add the label onto the layout

        self.txt1 = TextInput(text='', multiline=True) # create a text input instance
        grid.add_widget(self.txt1) # physically add the text input onto the layout

        self.lbl1 = ScrolllabelLabel(text='Display') # create a label instance
        grid.add_widget(self.lbl1) # physically add the label onto the layout

        btn1 = Button(text='Press') # create a button instance
        btn1.bind(on_press=self.mirror) # binding the button with the function below
        grid.add_widget(btn1) 

        return grid

    def mirror(self, userInput):
        self.lbl1.text = self.txt1.text

SomeApp().run()
```

Comment: I only used multiline properly and added the desired output manager(?). Use [Crash course](http://inclem.net/pages/kivy-crash-course/) to learn kivy quickly :)

Comment: I wonder what general guideline do you use to put the "self." in front of a variable within a function? I found it works with and without for some scenario. For example, why did you use self.lbl1 but not self.btn1?

Comment: That's how you access variables across the whole class e.g. functions `def func(self):` gives you access to variables directly under `class Something:` and with this you can even create those class variables via `self.variable` and use them later. Shortly said, something like globals for your class.